# Need help making file(s) smaller, losing disk space

Tags: linux, linux-mint

I am running Linux Mint 17.3 (64-bit, I think) Cinnamon, and I barely have any disk space left.

It's probably because there's this one folder I have with a bunch of files I downloaded from the Internet. I still need them, and I still need disk space too.

How do I compress all these files at once and make the resulting file as small as possible?

Comment: `baobab` / Disk Usage Analyzer is great for seeing what's taking up all the space. If the downloaded files were already in a big compressed archive, the archive may still be kicking around as well as the extracted files, easy redundant files to be deleted there

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please, for future questions, try to show some initiative, explaining what information have you looked for. [Here](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) are some more guidelines on how to ask a good question.

Answer (score 3):

If you downloaded all these files, they are most likely compressed - particularly if they end in .gz, .tgz, .zip, .deb, .gif, .jpg, .png.   Go out and purchase an external drive and move the data onto it.

Without knowing the file contents, its hard to advise a strategy to compress them - and its unlikely to do much any way.  7zip most likely offers the tightest compression, but I'd be very surprised if its worth the cost in time and CPU.

There is 1 exception I can think of - if there are lots and lots of tiny files, compressing them all into a single file can save significant space because of unused space at the end of each block - this doesn't seem to meet your objectivie though.

Another approach would be to look at your drive as a whole - it may be that your home directory is full, but other parts of the system are on different partitions - in which case you can make changes to where the data is stored to free up space - either by creating symlinks, a union-fs type solution or something else - but we would need to know your disk setup to advise this.